# Equation of a perpendicular line

Tags: linear-algebra

If the equation is $y=4x-2$ the equation of the perpendicular line that passes through $(a,b)$ is $$y=-1/4x+(b+a/4)$$ or not. Just trying to see if it’s right or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you find out it is $$y=-{1\over 4}x+n$$ Now if we plug $$b= -{1\over 4}a+n$$ we get $$ n= b+{a\over 4} = {4b+a\over 4}$$

and I suppose it is the same thing you think (but not written exactly).

Answer (score 1):

The line y= 4x- 2 has slope 4 so any perpendicular line has slope -1/4.

Any line with slope -1/4 can be written as y= (-1/4)x+ p for some constant p.  If that line passes through  (a, b) must have y= b when x= a:  b= (-1/4)a+ p so p= b+ (1/4)a.  The equation is y= (-1/4)x+ b+ (1/4)a.

That is, of course, the same as y= (-1/4)(x- a)+ b.